# Is there an open source Android email client?

Tags: java, android, email

I'm trying to create an email application which is depending upon the same function of our android mobile's default email application. How can I get that default email functions source code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is K-9 mail. It looks like you're in luck. it's open source on github: https://github.com/k9mail/k-9

Comment: i need that source code. Not an .apk file to install and run that. If you know means please tell me.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, I've edited my post. It's an open source project on Google Code/github.

Comment: K9 is one of the best. What they(at least when I looked at the code at an earlier time) did was take the Android E-mail source code and modified it for their own needs. There is no point in reinventing the wheel especially since E-mail is a massive and often complicated beast. If you need a small thing changed use K9.

Comment: Can I use K-9 email client in my client project ? to edit it and to build over it for free ?
Is it free software ?

Comment: @user1510006 yes you can. Its license is listed on the github page https://github.com/k9mail/k-9#license

Answer (score 8):

For sake of completeness, the source of the default Email application is available at

http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Email.git;a=summary.

EDIT: Palaniraja suggests the following alternate link, however it does not support the source browsing capability of the discontinued original repository.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Email/

However, it will (or at least used to) require a fair amount of adaptation before it can be built with the SDK, as it was originally designed to be built with the platform build system before decisions about APIs available under the SDK were finalized.  Unless that has changed, you may be better off working with some other codebase that someone has already adapted for SDK use.

Comment: The first link is broken/expired

Comment: That's why it is described as "discontinued" and there is a second one - though it is inferrior in interface to what *was* at the first.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help you: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html

i've used that for my own gmail client app.

Comment: The link is changed/removed. You should at least describe in brief what information is available at the mentioned link.

Comment: That was 5 years ago.

Comment: However, your answer is still here in 2016. And it doesn't provide any information.